# JFrame with JTabbedPane & JButton

Tags: jframe, jtabbedpane

I have a Jframe declared and adda JTabbedPane to it.

There are 4 tabbedPane and each has a table content.

Now, I need to add a refresh button to each tab, how can I do this?

This is how I'm doing:

```
frmSql = new JFrame();
JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
tabbedPane.addTab("Events", retrieveData("events"));

tabbedPane.addTab("Completed Events", retrieveData("completed"));
frmSql.add(tabbedPane);
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
static void createAndShowGui() {
    JFrame frmSql = new JFrame();
    JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
    Action refreshEvents = null, refreshCompletedEvents = null;
    tabbedPane.addTab("Events", createTab(retrieveData("events"), refreshEvents));
    // more tabs
    tabbedPane.addTab("Completed Events", createTab(retrieveData("completed"), refreshCompletedEvents));
    frmSql.setContentPane(tabbedPane);

}

static JComponent createTab(JComponent content, Action refreshAction) {
    JPanel p = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    p.add(content, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    JPanel btns = new JPanel();
    BoxLayout layout = new BoxLayout(btns, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS);
    btns.setLayout(layout);
    JButton refreshBtn = new JButton(refreshAction);
    btns.add(refreshBtn);
    btns.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
    p.add(btns, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
    return p;
}
```

Of course, if `retriveData` is time-consuming, it shouldn't be called from EDT

Comment: But the Tab is not reloading, how do i do that?